# Rails ActiveJob - What's the good way to handle exception in ActionMailer::DeliveryJob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, actionmailer, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I am using `ActiveJob` + `Sidekiq` in my Rails project for task processing.

I send my mails directly using `MyMailer.some.deliver_later`. It will automatically creates a `ActionMailer::DeliveryJob` task and put it in the `Sidekiq` queue.

The question is, what's the good to handle exceptions from there?

Best Regards.

Comment: Read this: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling

Comment: @KhAmmad Yes, I've read this. Does it mean you recommend to handle it with `config.error_handlers`?

Comment: Actually you shouldn't handle the exceptions, you should just let it fail, and then sidekiq will rescue the error for you, and mark the job as failed. If you want to receive some notifications, you can use some service like Airbrake or Honeybadger or Sentry.

Comment: yes, with `config.error_handlers` you can add your own handle.

Comment: @YuryLebedev Sometimes user enters a strangely bad email address, my mail service provider returns `501 SMTP command error` and sidekiq will just keep trying.

Comment: @KhAmmad that's something I already thought of. But with ActiveJob. If I do it at this level, I need to stick my hands into the args to get `job_class` for real `job_class`. I am here to see if there's any better ideas. Thanks.

Comment: @larryzhao as far as i know sidekiq has no retrying functionality, when using together with `ActiveJob`

Comment: @YuryLebedev really, I didn't dig into it, but in my queue they are retrying the same as a Sidekiq Worker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html, I think the good way is to setup exception error handlers for `ActionMailer::DeliveryJob` in an initializer, somethinglike:

```
ActionMailer::DeliveryJob.rescue_from(Net::SMTPSyntaxError) do |exception|
  unless ['501 Command parsing failed'].include?(exception.message.strip)
    raise exception
  end
end
```

Comment: How would you use this approach to display a meaningful message to a user currently logged into his account? Suppose the user input an email address and clicked a button "send" and it would get sent by deliver_later. How would the user get any feedback the delivery had failed?