# Rails after_perform for ActionMailer::DeliveryJob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

We use Sidekiq + ActionMailer in our rails application.

We want to do some post-actions after email is being sent. What is the best way to do something like `after_perform`.

- Should we override add `after_perform` callback as they suggested for exception handling [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33687374/227705)
- Can we extend default `ActionMailer::DeliveryJob` class with custom `after_perform` and specify somewhere in the configuration to use the custom class?

Comment: If you are using rails 4+ you can configure `ActiveJob` which already has `after_perform` callback  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#available-callbacks

Comment: Yes. It has. Is there a way to specify the configuration to make rails use the custom Job class instead of ActionMailer::DeliveryJob?

Answer (score 3):

About using a custom `Job` class: I believe you are now able to do just that.
[The PR enabling this feature](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/29457) has been merged 2 days ago. 
Cheers